# Scale up and move image from bottom right to top left with zoom out

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have used this answer to move and scale down the image (from top left to right bottom) and it is working fine..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564351/2389804

Now I want the reverse of this i.e. image to be scale up and move from bottom right to top left.. I have just replaced the source and destination and ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1, 0f, to ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 1, 1f ... 
scaling is working fine.. but image is still moving from top left to right bottom.. 
Can anyone help me out ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Per the link you shared : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564351/2389804

- Do not change your source and destination view
- Change Following Code :

  `ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1, 0f,
              Animation.ABSOLUTE, endX - startX + startView.getWidth() / 2,
              Animation.ABSOLUTE, endY - startY + startView.getHeight() / 2);`

To:

`ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0, 1f,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, endX - startX + startView.getWidth() / 2,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, endY - startY + startView.getHeight() / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as simple as this:

```
yourView.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).x(0.0f).y(0.0f);
```

This assumes `yourView`'s parent layout is the root layout in the hierarchy.